# How to set multiple getelementsbyid with if condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, getelementbyid, geoserver

[image]I need Little help.
I want to display my layer and legend with one single button. With this code i am adding both (legend and layer) But when i unchecked my button only layer is removing. I want to remove my legend too with the same button.

I am unable to adjust the code please guide me how to use multiple getelementByID with single if.

Button

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning"><label>Test Layer <input type="checkbox" id="testlayer" ></label></button>
```

and JS part is

```
testlayer.onclick = function() {

    var testlayerr = new TileLayer({
        source: new TileWMS({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wms',
            params: { 'LAYERS': 'MYDB:SoilMap' },
            serverType: 'geoserver',

            transition: 0,
        }),
    });


    var testlayer = new ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'MYDB:SoilMap' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',

        transition: 0,
    });[![enter image description here][1]][1]



    var updateLegend = function(resolution) {
        var graphicUrl = testlayer.getLegendUrl(resolution);
        var img = document.getElementById('legend');
        img.src = graphicUrl;

    };

    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    updateLegend(resolution);
   

    this.onclick = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("testlayer").checked) {
            map.addLayer(testlayerr);
        } else {

            map.removeLayer(testlayerr);
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById()` only ever returns one element. If you want to find multiple elements you can either use multiple getElementById() calls or instead add a class to the elements and use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which returns an HTMLCollection.

You have no code there to remove the legend. To hide the legend when the layer is hidden, your final `onclick` function needs to be something like:

```
// your HTML doesn't include the legend ID, so I've set a placeholder of "yourLegendElementId" 
this.onclick = function() {
  // find the legend element
  var legend = document.getElementById("yourLegendElementId");
  if (document.getElementById("testlayer").checked) {
    map.addLayer(testlayerr);
    // make sure the legend is visible
    legend.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    map.removeLayer(testlayerr);
    // make sure the legend is hidden
    legend.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

Comment: @FarrukhBukhari Would you mind marking the answer as accepted?